# How to install all required modules from gulpfile.js

Tags: npm, gulp

Is it possible install all required modules from gulpfile.js with command line?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Yes, you need to install the **npm-install-all** package.

After doing so, try below the commands, taken from the **Usage 1** subheading in the docs at [`npm-install-all`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-install-all):

> **Usage 1:**
>
> ```
> npm-install-all gulpfile.js
> ```

Comment: In case you get `npm-install-all: command not found`, run `npm install -g npm-install-all` first.

Comment: you need to install the package either project folder or global